# How to add a 2D array several times at the end of an existing 2D array using a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Starting point (boundary conditions):**

- There is a set of recurring events each week (weekly events section
  `row 9:11`).
- My colleagues can set a starting date `A6` and how many weeks they'd like to add `A5`.
  Start situation:[image]

**Goal:**
Running the script should add `A5` number of weeks starting from the date `A6` to the "upcoming events" section (`row 22 and following`) with the correct date.
This is how it would look like after the script ran successfully:[image]

**What works so far:**
The script is able to add the recurring events for one week in the right order to the upcoming events section. It works as well if the starting date is in the middle of the week. (Not shown here as it is probably not relevant.)

**My code:**

```
function recurringWeeks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // selects the active spreadsheet
  var repeatingWeeks = ss.getRange(5,1).getValue(); // gets how many weeks it should repeat
  var regWeek = ss.getRange(9, 2, 3, 7).getValues(); // gets the regular week data
  var regWeekRepeated = ss.getRange(9, 2, repeatingWeeks*3, 7); // create an array to store the events for all weeks

  // fill regWeekRepeated with regWeek
  for (var j = 0; j < repeatingWeeks; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      regWeekRepeated[i+j*3] = regWeek[i];
  }
  }  

  // Repeat week for "A5" times and add to start/end date a week
  for (var j = 0; j < repeatingWeeks; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    regWeekRepeated[i+j*3][0] = new Date(regWeek[i][0].getTime() + j*7*3600000*24); // <-This line leads to an error message.
    }
  }

  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,2,repeatingWeeks*3,7).setValues(regWeekRepeated); // copies weekly events after the last row
}
```

**Edit of [i+j*6] to [i+j*3] in** `Repeat week for "A5" times and add to start/end date a week`

**Approach:**
As I have solved how to add one week of recurring events with the correct date and right order, I use this as my "point of attack". I'm pretty sure that a `for-loop` does the job and this is currently my preferred tool.

- create an array (`regWeek`) filled with the recurring event for one 
  week with the right order and dates. **DONE**
- create an array (`regWeekRepeated`) and fill it with `A5` number of
  regular weeks (`regWeek`) starting from the date `A6`. **ERROR 1**:
  *Object does not allow properties to be added or changed.*
- make changes to the filled array `regWeekRepeated`. **ERROR 2**: *TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "(class)@3d8e4650"*
- Copy the values into the "upcoming events" section. **DONE**

**Best hit I've found in the search results:**
[creating 2 dimension arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575077/creating-2-dimension-arrays)
However, this uses .push and as far as I understand this means an element (can be a row) is placed at the end of an array. I've tried to use push as well but have not been successful yet.

**Questions**:

- ERROR 1: Why is it not possible to assign the value of an element from array `regWeek` to array `regWeekRepeated`? **Solved**
- ERROR 2: Is this property issue related to ERROR 1 or something different? I've tried to solve both errors individually. **Solved**
- Which approach makes more sense (logically or performance wise) in this context: push individual rows at the end of an existing array or use the whole week as array building blocks?

[A demo version of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NP7pPfcXiQGOjNFjVV0DeHZY0_fH1kExO_-FVQuAHsg/edit?usp=sharing)

**Update V01**:
Changes: regWeekRepeated is now an array.
I've changed the `for loop` due to the feedback I've received.

```
  // fill regWeekRepeated with regWeek
  var regWeekRepeated = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < repeatingWeeks; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      regWeekRepeated.push(regWeek[i]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(regWeekRepeated)
```

**Update V02**:

```
  // Repeat week for "A5" times and add to start/end date a week
  for (var j = 0; j < repeatingWeeks; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    regWeekRepeated[i+j*3][0] = new Date(regWeek[i][0].getTime() + j*7*3600000*24); //adds a week to the dates for each cycle
    //Logger.log(regWeekRepeated[i]); // log is as expected and desired
    }
    Logger.log(regWeekRepeated); // second part of log not as expected.
  }
  //Logger.log(regWeekRepeated);
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,2,repeatingWeeks*3,7).setValues(regWeekRepeated); // copies weekly events after the last row
```

Here the log output placed in the "outer" `for loop`.
[1 represents the first cycle, 2 the second cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuteg.png)
It looks like the second `for loop` overwrites the elements 0 to 2.

And here the output in [google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecoT.png)

**Update V03**:
This makes sure that the changes don't affect the copy.

```
  // fill regWeekRepeated with regWeek
  for (var j = 0; j < repeatingWeeks; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      regWeekRepeated[i+j*3] = regWeek[i].slice(); // shallow copy of an array
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regWeekRepeated` is not a array. `getRange()` doesn't return a array.

Try changing from

```
var regWeekRepeated = ss.getRange(9, 2, repeatingWeeks*3, 7); // create an array to store the events for all weeks
```

To

```
var regWeekRepeated = ss.getRange(9, 2, repeatingWeeks*3, 7).getValues(); // create an array to store the events for all weeks
```

Creating a array without touching the spreadsheet will increase performance.

```
var regWeekRepeated =[];
```

Comment: Getting values as proposed will create an array but not with meaningful data after the rows of the recurring events. This means starting with `var regWeekRepeated =[];` and filling it with regWeek values is probably better. Is this correct?

Comment: I've added my proposition at the end of my question under **Update V01**.

Comment: I've tried `var regWeekRepeated =[];` and the error messages are both gone. Nice! (A minor change had to be made. I added a comment below the code.) I'll post the current output of my code. The second `for loop`pair behaves unexpected (`Repeat week for "A5" times and add to start/end date a week`).

Comment: FYI: The adapted code and output is posted at the end of the question under Update V02. It seems there is a flaw in my logic of the `for loop`.

Comment: The output in sheets for `j` starting with 1 is identical to starting with 0. I'd expect it to be the same because the first loop should not add anything. It appears that the code overwrites `regWeekRepeated` rows 1-3 with 4-6.

Comment: I'd expect the following behavior.
First step: `regWeekRepeated` is filled with values of `regWeek`
Second step **version A**: `for loop` with conditions j=0,i=0, [i+j*3]=0 or row 1 of `regWeekRepeated` runs and copies row 1 of `regWeek` (without adding a week because `j=0, j*7days=0`).This means the values stay the same for the first cycle `(j=0)`. The second cycle (`j=1`) adds 7 days to row 4-6 of `regWeekRepeated`.
Second step **version B**: `for loop` with conditions j=1,i=0, [i+j*3]=3 or row 4 of `regWeekRepeated` runs and copies row 1 of `regWeek` + 7days.

Comment: The rows 1-3 are already filled with data from regWeek because of step 1 **in version B**.

Comment: One second, I'll re-run the script to make sure, I explain the behavior correctly.

Comment: Correct. I'd like to have rows 1-3 with the orignial data and rows 4-6 with the newly added data (+7 days). The logger shows that this is done with both versions. However, the output in google sheets shows for both versions https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecoT.png

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the direction! I'll read through the two questions, apply it and update what I find out.

Comment: Awesome! I've tested it as well and it works exactly as intended. As a summary: there are different ways of copying an array. Depending which one is chosen, altering an array might affect a copy. I'll digest the information from the links you've posted and experiment with them. I'll update my question with your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Neither do I. I'm trying to find some bread crumbs in the links you've posted pointing to an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Making scripts for spreadsheets could be tricked because the spreadsheet and JavaScript jargons/lexics use the same terms in different ways. Perhaps this is what is happening here.

> - ERROR 1: Why is it not possible to assign the value of an element from array `regWeek` to array `regWeekRepeated`?

regWeekRepeated is a Range object not a JavaScript Array

> - ERROR 2: Is this property issue related to ERROR 1 or something different? I've tried to solve both errors individually.

Yes it's related. See the previous answer.

> - Which approach makes more sense (logically or performance wise) in this context: push individual rows at the end of an existing array or use the whole week as array building blocks?

We could say that calling Google Apps Scripts classes and methods are "expensive" so we should try to minimize the number calls to these kind of elements. One way to do this is by passing the range values to a JavaScript Array , then make all the changes directly to it and we finish pass the resulting values to the corresponding range.

To pass the values of a range to a JavaScript 2D array, use range.getValues() and to pass the JavaScript 2D array values to a range use range.setValues().

Comment: I assume you mean regWeekRepeated **is** a Range object not a JavaScript Array. I've changed my code based on the feedback of @I'-'I and created an array with`var regWeekRepeated =[];`. ERROR 1 is resolved by this. Regarding the performance question: I learned that one should minimize the number of calls of Google Apps Scripts classes/methods. The focus of my question is: it is performance wise better to add each row individually or the recurring events batch wise? (Or is the difference relatively small and can be neglected?)

Comment: Regarding the first part, you are right, I fixed that.